# Codeigniter 2 Good Practices

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am deciding to do all the new code/functionality to be done in CI 2. I am a complete noob in CI . What are the do and fonts that you recommend. Also what is the best way to call existing code with CI. Old code is just normal PHP with classes/functions at a few places.

Also let me know what all do i need to read before i begin.

Comment: Don't use CI.  There are better frameworks out there.

Comment: @GordonM You should list the better frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to re-user your old code - use CI libraries. But please note that you might have to change a few things in your old code for it to work.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html

I'd strongly advise you to read through the whole (or atleast part of) CI manual/user guide.

You might want to read through this before beginning to work with CI. It has some good points.
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html

And on a related note - you might want to read through the PHP manuals OOP section first. And perhaps google 'MVC arhitecture'.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the user guide: [Codeigniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/). Take a few days and go through all the topics.  Or you can download Codeigniter and go through the user guide locally. Then start developing small applications like a CRUD and adding more features that you had gone through.